# Looping through a pandas dataframe - how to make code run faster?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, **df**, with 43244 rows, and a txt file, **text** with 1107957 lines. The purpose of the following code is to evaluate entries in df, and return a word_id value if they are present in the text.

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
    text = f.readlines()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    lemma_id = 0
    for lines in range(len(text)):
        word_row = text[lines].split()
        if word_row[2] == row['Word']:
            word_id = word_row[1]
    row['ID'] = word_id
```

However, this code would take an estimated 120 days to complete in my jupyter notebook, and I (obviously) want it to execute a bit more efficiently.

How do I approach this? Should I convert **text** into a dataframe/database, or is there another more efficient approach?

**EDIT**

Example of dataframe structure:

```
                        Word       ID
0                       hello      NaN
1                       there      NaN
```

Example of txt.file structure:

```
NR      ID      WORD    
32224   86289   ah  
32225   86290   general 
32226   86291   kenobi
```

Comment: It isn't entirely clear without some sample data but it certainly looks like you could read your text file into a data frame or series and do an inner join...

Comment: Added some sample data to illustrate the structure of the txt and df

Comment: It would probably good to a) give some sample data where you have at leat one match and b) give the expected output

Comment: @LarsLill if you can convert the text file to df the processing time will be much shorter ? have you tried this ? Also do not use iterrows. You can use df.to_dict() instead of iterrows()

Comment: Converted it to a df now and trying the to_dict method, but I'm getting the error message TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment in the last line where I try to assign the value.

Comment: In general, you want to be using itertuples and not iterrows to iterate rows of a Pandas dataframe when you care about speed. See [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/heres-the-most-efficient-way-to-iterate-through-your-pandas-dataframe-4dad88ac92ee) and [here](https://medium.com/swlh/why-pandas-itertuples-is-faster-than-iterrows-and-how-to-make-it-even-faster-bc50c0edd30d). To me this looks like you'd want to us vectorized methods inside Pandas like `.value_counts()` and collect that in new dataframe and then convert that dataframe to your output file. But I didn't study your code much.

Comment: Oh wait, Clegane said some of this already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `pandas.merge`?

Your `for` loop would be replaced by the following (assuming that `text` is a DataFrame)

```py
new_df = pd.merge(df, text_df, left_on='WORD', right_on='Word')
new_df.dropna(subset=['ID'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: This gives the desired results if I comment out line nr 2, which results in an empty dataframe. This may be due to differences between the sample code/values in this question and my actual code/data - I will give you the chance to doublecheck this before marking the answer as correct.

Comment: In the example, all ID are NaN so it ends up dropping all of them. My understanding is that there will always be a word in the text dataset but it might not have an ID. Hence, when it does have an ID, it will not be dropped. If the first line does what you intended, then this solution is good to go.